# Pure CSS menu show/hide transition is very slow

Tags: html, css

Got a pure CSS mobile friendly menu working really nicely, except it's really slow on an actual mobile device.

Here's a [link](https://ib4.mybluemix.net/)

If you shrink down to 320px or so, or you open it on a mobile phone, and click the menu (hamburger) icon up top, you get the navigation menu below. On mobile, and on certain page (with images near the top) it's very slow.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm using this method for the most part: [link](http://v)

I am transitioning the font-size and height of an display:inline nav element. Basically font and height go to zero and back when you check and uncheck the checkbox (via the label, which is the menu icon)

Any help, or even ideas on a different way to accomplish the same thing (no javascript) would rock!

Some relevant CSS (stylus):

```
  #nav-toggle (input of type checkbox)
    position absolute
    top 0
    visibility hidden

  #nav-toggle-label (the label of the above input)
    cursor pointer
    color coal
    font-size 3em

  #nav-toggle-label
    display inline-block
    width 30%
    vertical-align middle
    padding .5em 0 0 0

  #nav-toggle-label img
    height 40px

  #nav-toggle:checked ~ #nav
    height 0px
    font-size 0em
```

Comment: You are aware of the page being completely minified and not readable? Can you post the actual CSS here so perhaps we can look at the transition timing?

Comment: Completely minified? (like gzip minification?) Not readable? Like the font is too small in some parts?

Comment: Yes, I can put some relevant CSS up.

Comment: No, not obfuscated - but not human parsable

Comment: Rather than having your browser repaint the font-size and height (which is very expensive).. try animating the `transform: scale()` of the elements instead.

Comment: Ah, yes, jade is doing some minifying, sorry, the html isn't super readable, it needs formatting. Helps with display:inline-block whitespace issues though : )

Comment: So, using scale on it's own isn't helpful because the DOM element still has it's original height, and so clicking the menu just leaves a big white space in there.